# Latex crashes with no errors shown

Tags: errors

My code isn't compiling any more, first time in several months, I haven't been able to find what's wrong, it doesn't even show any errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt,spanish]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.7cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{imakeidx}%for indexes
\makeindex[name=terms,title=\'Indice alfab\'etico,columns=2]
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}


\usepackage{pifont}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.0001in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{.0001in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.8in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{.0001in}




\def\I{{\cal I}}

\newcommand{\chapquote}[3]{\begin{quotation} \textit{#1} \end{quotation} \begin{flushright} - #2, \textit{#3}\end{flushright} }
\newcommand{\chapquoteit}[2]{\begin{quotation} \textit{#1} \end{quotation} \begin{flushright} - #2\end{flushright} }

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{#2}}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{\textbf{Notaci\'on}: }

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ding{110}}

\newcommand{\uprint}[2]{
  \overline{\int_{#1}^{#2}}
}
\newcommand{\lorint}[2]{
  \underline{\int_{#1}^{#2}}}

\newcommand{\bs}{\boldsymbol}

\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}

\DeclareMathOperator\ext{Ext}

\DeclareMathOperator\Rea{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator\Ima{Im}

\DeclareMathOperator\Int{Int}

\DeclareMathOperator\grad{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator\Id{Id}

\DeclareMathOperator\ev{ev}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\DeclareMathOperator\Alt{Alt}

\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}

\newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}

  \newenvironment{dedication}
{
   \cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
   \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
   \raggedright
   \itshape
}%
{
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
   \clearpage
}
\newcommand\smallO{
  \mathchoice
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \displaystyle
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \textstyle
    {{\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \scriptstyle
    {\scalebox{.5}{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}$}}%\scriptscriptstyle
  }

  \makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
  \null
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}\leavevmode
    \normalfont
    {\LARGE\raggedleft \@author\par}%
    \hrulefill\par
    {\huge\raggedright \@title\par}%
    \vskip 1cm
%    {\Large \@date\par}%
  \end{center}%
  \vfill
  \null
  \cleardoublepage
  }
\makeatother
\author{Sebasti\'an N\'ajera Valencia}
\title{Notas de C\'alculo III 2017-1}
\date{ }

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[chapter] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definici\'on} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers
\newtheorem{eg}[thm]{Ejemplo} % same for example numbers
\newtheorem{lema}[thm]{Lema}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{nb}[thm]{\textbf{N.B.}}
\newtheorem{obs}[thm]{\textbf{Obs.}}



\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Acronym,Description
N.B., N\'otese bien.
I.E., Es decir.
C.f., Consulte.
E.G., Por ejemplo.
S.P.G., Sin p\'erdida de generalidad.
$\mathcal{D}(f)$ $(\mathcal{R}(f))$, Dominio (Rango) de $f$.
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{acronyms.tex}
\section*{Notaci\'on y abreviaturas}
\begin{itemize}
\DTLforeach*{acronyms}{\thisAcronym=Acronym,\thisDesc=Description}%
  {\item \textbf{\thisAcronym} \thisDesc}%
\end{itemize}
\printnomenclature
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{acronyms}{test.csv}
\DTLsort{Acronym}{acronyms}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter

\chapter{Prefacio}
En este curso se generalizar\'an los conceptos que se vieron en el primer curso de C\'alculo, se desarrollar\'a toda la teor\'ia matem\'atica para poder justificar la derivaci\'on como operador lineal y los teoremas asociados a esta poderosa herramienta aunque se asumir\'a que los estudiantes llevan a la par un curso de \'Algebra Lineal en donde ver\'a muchas de las demostraciones que se omiten en dichas notas, as\'i como profundizar\'a en conceptos que en ocasiones solamente se mencionan o se utilizan para desarrollar otros. Dado lo anterior, es necesario introducir conceptos de otras \'areas de las matem\'aticas, que en principio podr\'ian parecerle al estudiante ajenas al an\'alisis, como el \'algebra lineal y la topolog\'ia, finalmente, uno de los objetivos del curso es que el estudiante pueda apreciar la interacci\'on entre distintas ramas de las matem\'aticas. As\'i, el curso comienza con una revisi\'on de los conceptos de espacios vectoriales y una introducci\'on a la topolog\'ia, en particular se ver\'a la de $\mathbb{R}^n$. \\

Dado que el curso toca de manera natural ciertos conceptos de Geometr\'ia Diferencial, es una buena excusa para dar una introducci\'on a la teor\'ia de curvas, as\'i como otros conceptos de esta bella rama de las matem\'aticas que surgen en el camino. Dados mis propios intereses, es natural que en ocasiones se toquen temas relacionados con la f\'isica matem\'atica, nunca ahondando en ellos dado que este es un curso de m\'atematicas, y, como se mencion\'o antes, de Geometr\'ia Diferencial. Cabe destacar que el curso de C\'alculo Diferencial III es un curso esencial en la formaci\'on de un f\'isico, actuario y matem\'atico. As\'imismo, esta materia da los fundamentos b\'asicos para poder estudiar otros problemas interesantes, como es la electrodin\'amica, con el estudio de las ecuaciones diferenciales parciales, y el estudio de membranas, con t\'ecnicas de geometr\'ia diferencial.\\

Con el paso del tiempo, cada rama de la actuar\'ia, las matem\'aticas y la f\'isica se han vuelto m\'as especializadas y requieren interactuar cada vez m\'as con otros campos del conocimiento. Sobre todo, dentro de la parte te\'orica de estas \'areas se requiere que el estudiante interesado en adentrarse a la frontera del conocimiento del \'area que le es de su inter\'es, sepa una gran cantidad de matem\'aticas, que como bien se sabe es el lenguaje de las ciencias exactas. \\

Es importante destacar que dichas notas cubren un temario un tanto distinto al que se ofrece en la mayor\'ia de los cursos de C\'alculo III en la Facultad de Ciencias, aunque se cubre dicho temario. La raz\'on de este cambio es proporcionar a los estudiantes una visi\'on distinta de la poderosa herramienta que es el C\'alculo Diferencial y sus aplicaciones no se limitan a espacios euclideanos. Creo que el desarrollo de estas notas se ha tornado en una especie de \emph{introducci\'on al an\'alisis}, las cuales espero le sirvan al estudiante como puente entre las materias de C\'alculo y An\'alisis. De misma manera, espero que aquellos estudiantes que no lleven la materia de An\'alisis puedan apreciar el poder de este y que los espacios no euclideanos son m\'as comunes de lo que uno cree, al fin y al cabo vivimos en un mundo no euclideano y las matem\'aticas que requerimos para describir muchos de los fen\'omenos que suceden requieren inclusive de espacios de dimensi\'on infinita como, por ejemplo, en la Mec\'anica Cu\'antica.\\

Estas notas las hice de tal manera que los estudiantes tuvieran acceso a casi todo el curso, podr\'ia estar equivocado pero asumo que agrego pero tambi\'en peco de omitir palabras en la exposici\'on de estas notas. En la elaboraci\'on de \'estas consider\'e diversos textos, dado que la exposici\'on de los diversos libros de C\'alculo Multivariable realizan diversas suposiciones sobre los conocimientos previos de los estudiantes. Existen excelentes libros sobre el tema, aunque uno como estudiante generalmente se apega al libro que utiliza el profesor en su clase. Como mis estudiantes del curso anterior sabr\'an, utilizo diversos fuentes, en ocasiones utilizo una misma pero tambi\'en complemento con alg\'un otro libro que \emph{tenga algo importante que decir, un enfoque distinto o alg\'un ejemplo interesante}, por lo que estas notas de ninguna manera son un trabajo original sino una recopilaci\'on de los diversos textos que consider\'e eran las mejores fuentes para cada tema, todas se encuentran citadas en la bibliograf\'ia. \\ 

Espero que les sean \'utiles \'estas notas. Sobre todo que les sirvan para algo distinto que pasar este curso, 
\begin{flushright}
Sebasti\'an N\'ajera
\end{flushright}

\chapter{Cambios y observaciones}

Se sugiere que el estudiante tome notas en clase, no se asegura que estas notas se encuentren al d\'ia ni que est\'en libres de errores, de encontrar alguno o tienen alg\'un comentario o cr\'itica constructiva a las notas favor de avisar a Sebasti\'an.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Se agregaron algunas correcciones al cap\'itulo \ref{cap4}. Hab\'ian algunos \'indices con errores. Se movi\'o Banach al cap\'itulo 5 donde creo que es m\'as natural que se estudie.
\item Se agregaron algunas correcciones de estilo.
\item Dadas las correcciones que consideramos pertinentes cambi\'o la enumeraci\'on de gran parte de las notas, pero las referencias a teoremas son correctas.
\item Insistimos en que deben tomar notas, dado que las notas cambian continuamente y es posible que cambien en gran medida. Asimismo las notas contienen errores, los cuales en ocasiones olvidamos corregir por lo que es muy recomendable que tomen notas, estamos conscientes de que las notas contienen todo tipo de errores pero dado que las notas las iremos limpiando con el paso del tiempo consideramos que el estudiante debe comparar sus notas de clase con estas notas. As\'imismo, el hacer notas es una buena manera de que el estudiante constantemente est\'e estudiando y ponga atenci\'on en clase.
\item Queda pendiente agregar algunos ejemplos de clase, as\'i como correcciones a las notas, si encuentran errores en las notas agradecer\'ia que me los hicieran notar para poder corregirlos. Tambi\'en sugerencias o quejas de redacci\'on, es probable que al mover ciertas secciones no me haya dado cuenta de la redacci\'on y que no haya cierta continuidad. 
\item Cualquier referencia con \ref{inexistente} hace referencia a material que se ver\'a m\'as adelante, conforme avancemos en el curso estas referencias se corregir\'an.
\end{enumerate}

\include{acronyms}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

% Length to control the \fancyheadoffset and the calculation of \headline
% simultaneously
\newlength\FHoffset
\setlength\FHoffset{0cm}

\addtolength\headwidth{2\FHoffset}

\fancyheadoffset{\FHoffset}

% these lengths will control the headrule trimming to the left and right 
\newlength\FHleft
\newlength\FHright

% here the trimmings are controlled by the user
\setlength\FHleft{0cm}
\setlength\FHright{-1.5cm}

% The new definition of headrule that will take into acount the trimming(s)
\newbox\FHline
\setbox\FHline=\hbox{\hsize=\paperwidth%
  \hspace*{\FHleft}%
  \rule{\dimexpr\headwidth-\FHleft-\FHright\relax}{\headrulewidth}\hspace*{\FHright}%
}
\renewcommand\headrule{\vskip-.7\baselineskip\copy\FHline}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\iffalse
\include{tex/cap1}

\include{tex/cap2}


\include{tex/cap3}

\include{tex/cap4}

\include{tex/cap5}
\include{tex/epi}
\fi


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\'Indice alfab\'etico}
\printindex[terms]

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

  \bibitem{apostol}
T. ~Apostol, (2001). \emph{Calculus, Vol. II.} M\'exico. Revert\'e.

  \bibitem{apostol}
V. ~Arnold, (1989). \emph{Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics.} Estados Unidos. Springer-Verlag.


  \bibitem{Bartle}
R.~Bartle, (1976). \emph{The Elements of Real Analysis.} Estados Unidos. Wiley.


  \bibitem{Boothby}
W.~Boothby, (1986). \emph{An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry.} Estados Unidos. Academic Press.

  \bibitem{choquet}
Y.~Choquet-Bruhat, C. ~DeWitt-Morette (1982). \emph{Analysis, Manifolds and Physics, Part 1: Basics.} Estados Unidos. North Holland.

  \bibitem{devinatz}
A. ~Devinatz (1968). \emph{Advanced Calculus.} Estados Unidos. Holt, Rinehart and Winston.

\bibitem{dieudonne}
J. ~Dieudonn\'e (1979). \emph{Fundamentos de An\'alisis Moderno.} Espa\~na. Revert\'e.

  \bibitem{docarmo}
M. ~Do Carmo, (1976). \emph{Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces.} Estados Unidos. Prentice-Hall.

  \bibitem{edwards}
H. ~Edwards (1994). \emph{Advanced Calculus: A Differential Forms Approach.} Estados Unidos. Birkh\"auser.

  \bibitem{fleming}
W. ~Fleming (1987). \emph{Functions of Several Variables (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics).} Estados Unidos. Springer.

  \bibitem{friedberg}
S. ~Friedberg, A. ~Insel, L. ~Spence (2002). \emph{Linear Algebra.} Estados Unidos. Pearson.
  \bibitem{hoffman}
A. ~Hoffman, R. ~Kunze, (1971). \emph{Linear Algebra.} Estados Unidos. Prentice-Hall.
  \bibitem{Kolmo}
A. N. ~Kolmogorov, S. V. ~Fom\'in, (1975). \emph{Elementos de la teor\'ia de funciones y del an\'alisis funcional.} URSS. Mir.

  \bibitem{lang}
S. ~Lang (1996). \emph{Calculus of Several Variables (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics).} Estados Unidos. Springer.

  \bibitem{loomis} 
L.~Loomis, S. ~Sternberg, (1990). \emph{Advanced Calculus.} Estados Unidos. Johns \& Bartlett Publishing.

 \bibitem{mcshane}
E. J. ~McShane, (1973). \emph{The Lagrange Multiplier Rule.} Amer. Math. Monthly, 80, 922-925.

  \bibitem{munkres}
J. ~Munkres, (2008). \emph{Analysis on Manifolds.} Estados Unidos. Westview Press.

  \bibitem{nicker}
H.K. ~Nickerson, D.C. ~Spencer, N.E. ~Steenrod (2011). \emph{Advanced Calculus.} Estados Unidos. Dover.

  \bibitem{oneill}
B. ~O'Neill, (1972). \emph{Elementos de Geometr\'ia Diferencial.} M\'exico. Limusa.

  \bibitem{spivak}
M. ~Spivak, (2004). \emph{C\'alculo en Variedades.} M\'exico. Revert\'e.

  \bibitem{spivakg1}
M. ~Spivak, (2005). \emph{A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry Vol I.} Estados Unidos. Publish or Perish.

  \bibitem{spivakg2}
M. ~Spivak, (1999). \emph{A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry Vol II.} Estados Unidos. Publish or Perish.

\end{thebibliography}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{aipsamp}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

\end{document}
```

I put `iffalse` on the extra files and still doesn't compile. Would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Welcome! Please reduce your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. What is in the log file? What does get printed on the console when you try to compile?

Comment: `("C:/Users/Sebastian/Dropbox/notas/Cálculo III/Notas\Notas Master.aux")
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
("C:/Users/Sebastian/Dropbox/notas/Cálculo III/Notas\Notas Master.out"
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.71 ... \futurelet \@let@token ndice.alph1.Alph1}
                                                  % 71
? ` These are the last lines of the console

Comment: Make sure that you remove all generated files before recompiling after commenting out the included files. You don't need the included files in your example here if you can reproduce the issue without them.

Comment: Do you need all those packages? Note that `hyperref` should be loaded last unless you have a package that specially wants to come later (e.g. `cleveref`. Is your `.tex` file really using `latin1` encoding? Most editors now use UTF-8 by default. If you are loading `geometry` then you must not set page layout dimensions manually because `geometry` needs to know about the changes you make. Your macro definitions are introducing spurious spaces. `\def\I` is dangerous. Are you sure nothing has defined this command before? Why not `\newcommand*\I`?

Comment: It is crashing while reading in files from previous compilations. Delete those generated files and recompile at least twice. If the problem goes away, the issue is probably in one of the included files. If not, delete the included stuff and start reducing the remaining code to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: When I erased hyperref it worked, but it's taking more time than usual, I'll erase previous files I'll hope it works thanks

Comment: It already worked, but it's taking a lot of time, why could it be?

Comment: What worked and what's taking a lot of time?

Comment: It's not crashing anymore, but compilation time is longer than it used to be, its about two minutes when it used to be a couple of seconds, it sometimes freezes and windows says stopped working

Comment: Compile interactively to see if you can see what takes the time. Look in the log. If you compile other documents, do they take longer? If it is document specific, create a more minimal example to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

You have not one but *two* `\bibliography` statements, *plus* you appear to create a bibliography entirely "by hand", from `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` to `\end{thebibliography}`. If I comment out the statements `\bibliography{biblio}` and `\bibliography{aipsamp}`, I can get your document to compile.

Of course, there may be further issues, in the files `cap1.tex` through `cap5.tex` and `epi.tex`. However, your code has excluded them from being included in the main document.